# Beginnings of a neuron simulation

Tags: python, object-oriented, simulation, pygame

I have 2 classes that do extremely similar things. The only differences are that they draw using different colors, and that one draws in the back.

The classes `NeuronOutput` and `NeuronReciever` are very similar.

```
class NeuronOutput():
    """The place where a Neuron outputs its signal"""
    def __init__(self,neuron):
        self.neuron=neuron

        width=self.neuron.width*0.5
        offset=width/2
        distance=self.neuron.width*0.4
        self.pos=[self.neuron.x+math.sin(self.neuron.angle)*distance,self.neuron.y-math.cos(self.neuron.angle)*distance]
        self.drawRect=[self.pos[0]-offset,self.pos[1]-offset,width,width]        
    def draw(self,surf):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(surf,[200,150,200],self.drawRect)
class NeuronReciever():
    """Where a Neuron recieves input"""
    def __init__(self,neuron):
        self.neuron=neuron

        width=self.neuron.width*0.5
        offset=width/2
        distance=self.neuron.width*0.4
        self.pos=[self.neuron.x-math.sin(self.neuron.angle)*distance,self.neuron.y+math.cos(self.neuron.angle)*distance]
        self.drawRect=[self.pos[0]-offset,self.pos[1]-offset,width,width]        
    def draw(self,surf):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(surf,[200,255,200],self.drawRect)
```

There is also a class `Neuron` that uses instances of the two above classes as properties. It is also fairly similar to them, however it is a bit different in the way it initializes and draws.

```
class Neuron():
    """A single neuron with Synapses that connect to others"""
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.pos=[x,y]
        self.width=30
        self.drawOffset=self.width/2;
        self.connections=[]
        self.angle=math.radians(random.randint(0,360))
        self.drawRect=[self.x-self.drawOffset,self.y-self.drawOffset,self.width,self.width]
        self.output=NeuronOutput(self)
        self.input=NeuronReciever(self)

    def draw(self,surf):

        pygame.draw.ellipse(surf,[200,150,50],self.drawRect)
        self.output.draw(surf)
        self.input.draw(surf)
        self.syn.draw(surf)
```

(The code is the beginning of a neuron simulation.)

I want to keep all these as separate classes for the sake of readability and ease of use. **How can I reduce the repetitiveness of this code, while still keeping it readable?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have two classes which are very similar and differ only in one thing? Then make a parent class that has all the behavior and let the others inherit from it or add a switch to flip between the two behaviors.

I would probably go with the first. To accomplish this, make `self.drawRect` a `property` (and rename it to `self.rect`, it does not actually draw anything, it just says where to draw):

```
class NeuronIO:
    """Draw input or output of a neuron.

    Abstract base class.
    """
    color = 0, 0, 0  # default color is black

    def __init__(self, neuron):
        self.neuron = neuron

        width = 0.5 * self.neuron.width
        offset = width / 2
        distance = 0.4 * self.neuron.width
        self._pos = None
        self._rect = None

    def draw(self, surf):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(surf, self.color, self.rect)

    @property
    def pos(self):
        """Needs to be implemented by the child classes"""
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def rect(self):
        if self._rect is None:
            pos = self.pos
            self._rect = pos[0] - offset, pos[1] - offset, width, width 
        return self._rect


class NeuronOutput(NeuronIO):
    """The place where a Neuron outputs its signal"""
    color = 200, 150, 200

    @property
    def pos(self):
        if self._pos is None:
            self._pos = (self.neuron.x + math.sin(self.neuron.angle) * distance,
                         self.neuron.y - math.cos(self.neuron.angle) * distance)
        return self._pos


class NeuronReciever(NeuronIO):
    """Where a Neuron receives input"""
    color = 200, 255, 200
    @property
    def pos(self):
        if self._pos is None:
            self._pos = (self.neuron.x - math.sin(self.neuron.angle) * distance,
                         self.neuron.y + math.cos(self.neuron.angle) * distance)
        return self._pos
```

Here both `rect` and `pos` are cached so that they are only calculated the first time they are needed.

In addition I added some whitespace around operators and after commas, as recommended by Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

At this point you should ask yourself: "But how often do I need to draw the receiver or output without also drawing a neuron?". If the answer to that question is "probably never!", then you should just fold all of that functionality into the `Neuron` class:

```
import math
import random
import pygame


class Neuron:
    """A single neuron with Synapses that connect to others"""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pos = x, y
        self.width = 30
        self.offset = self.width / 2
        self.connections = []
        self.angle = math.radians(random.randint(0, 360))
        self.rect = (self.x - self.offset, self.y - self.offset,
                     self.width, self.width)
        self.color = 200, 150, 50

    def draw(self, surf):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(surf, self.color, self.rect)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(surf, *self.input)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(surf, *self.output)

    @property
    def input(self):
        color = 200, 255, 200
        rect = self.calc_rect()
        return color, rect

    @property
    def output(self):
        color = 200, 255, 200
        rect = self.calc_rect(output=True)
        return color, rect

    def calc_rect(self, output=False):
        width = 0.5 * self.width
        distance = 0.4 * self.width
        offset = 0.25 * self.width
        if output:
            pos = (self.x + math.sin(self.angle) * distance,
                   self.y - math.cos(self.angle) * distance)
        else:
            pos = (self.x - math.sin(self.angle) * distance,
                   self.y + math.cos(self.angle) * distance)
        return pos[0] - offset, pos[1] - offset, width, width
```

Here I did not go through the effort of making sure that `Neuron.input` and `Neuron.output` are only calculated once, but you could do it in the same way as I did above.

Note that I made all of your lists into tuples (like `Neuron.pos`). This is just aesthetics atm, but if you want to be able to do e.g. `neuron.pos[0] += 1`, then you need to make them lists again.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and is quite helpful! p.s. you missed that they draw in different colors. `color` is the second argument of `pygame.draw.ellipse`

Comment: @pydude Fixed, made the color custom as well.

Comment: @pydude And I added some code for the case that this should not actually be standalone classes.